# Group cohomology with the coefficient $\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite group which has a $G$-module $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.

Note that $\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}$ is $n$-torsion subgroup of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$.

It is my purpose to give a map from $H^{i}(G;\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z})$ to $H^{i}(G;\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z})$.

As we do for the singular cohomology with coefficients, my attempt is to use the tensor product $\otimes\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{Z}/\mathbb{Z}$.

However i am not sure that this is the right method for it.

Thank you for your time and effort.

Comment: Alas $(\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z)\otimes(\frac1n\Bbb Z/\Bbb Z)=0$.